# Kubernetes internal only ingress

Tags: azure, kubernetes, dns, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks

I'm trying Kubernetes in a Azure environment (AKS).

I have an nginx ingress deployed and exposed to internet through a public ip and an azure load balancer. It is used to expose public/front services.

My issue is I would like to deploy 'back' services, not exposed to internet. My first guess would be to deploy a second ingress and expose it on the internal load balancer, am I right ?

But what if my front services needs to consume the back services, can I consume it over the second ingress (to use nginx configuration, ssl offload, etc) but not do a round trip to the internal load balancer. What will be the DNS configuration in that case?

Comment: Are the front and back services on the same AKS cluster?

Comment: why do you want ingress? why cant you just use kubernetes services?

Comment: @4c74356b41 Services doesn't allow you to mix paths to serve different apps pointing to separate services like Ingress

Comment: why do you need that? each service can have its own endpoint

Answer (score 2):

Ingress controllers are made for external traffic. For in-cluster communication it is best to use [Kubernetes Services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) which will configure the DNS inside the cluster. With a Service you'll be able to call your backend service without doing a roundtrip to an external resource, the load balancing will be done natively inside the k8s cluster. Nothing prevent you from deploying an nginx pod or inject it as a sidecar in your backend service pod and use it as a reverse proxy, but do you really the nginx configuration and mutual TLS for in-cluster communication? If you really need mutual TLS, you better look at something like [Istio](https://istio.io/), but it is probably overkill for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to deploy a secondary ingress service. All you need to do is make your service endpoint [IP] private and they should be able to talk to your ingress service only.

So how you create a private IP: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress-internal-ip